# Create a category column out from two category columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this dataframe

```
d = {
    'Primary area': [
        'Biological Sciences A',
        'Cultures and Cultural Production',
        'Mathematics'
    ],
    'Discipline': [
        'Biochemistry and Molecular Biology',
        'Philosophy',
        'Pure Mathematics'
    ]
}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    Discipline                              Primary area
0   Biochemistry and Molecular Biology      Biological Sciences A
1   Philosophy                              Cultures and Cultural Production
2   Pure Mathematics                        Mathematics
```

I want to obtain a new column, "Mydisciplines" column, that depending on the row takes on an item from "Discipline" or from "Primary area". I have a list of words

```
Mydisciplines = ['Biological Sciences A', 'Mathematics', 'Philosophy']
```

and I want to use this new list to filter both columns and then merge what's left. Such as

```
    Discipline                           Mydisciplines          Primary area
0   Biochemistry and Molecular Biology   Biological Sciences A  Biological Sciences A
1   Philosophy                           Philosophy             Cultures and Cultural Production
2   Pure Mathematics                     Mathematics            Mathematics
```

I tried a few things but I'm not being able to synthesise what I want in a piece of code.
I'm quite lost on how to approach this problem.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, hope it's easier now.

Comment: How do you decide which column to choose?

Comment: There's a long list of Primary area and a long list of disciplines. I decided which I want to take from each, there's no rationale just a matter of choice. So I need to be able to say: use this list, compare and select the column Primary area and select and compare the Discipline column, but the order in the rows has to be respected as that's my data, it's quite simple but I'm struggling to put in words

Comment: So you will always have exactly one of "Disciplines" and "Primary area" for each row in "Mydisciplines"?  Never neither, and never both?

Comment: yep! neither both nor neither, exactly one from one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by joined all values of `Mydisciplines` by `|` for regex `OR` and `\b` for word boundary:

```
Mydisciplines = ['Biological Sciences A', 'Mathematics', 'Philosophy']

pat = r'(\b{}\b)'.format('|'.join(Mydisciplines))

#join columns together
s = df['Discipline'] + ' ' + df['Primary area']

df['Mydisciplines'] = s.str.extract(pat, expand=False)
print (df)
                           Discipline                      Primary area  \
0  Biochemistry and Molecular Biology             Biological Sciences A   
1                          Philosophy  Cultures and Cultural Production   
2                    Pure Mathematics                       Mathematics   

           Mydisciplines  
0  Biological Sciences A  
1             Philosophy  
2            Mathematics
```

Comment: I have a mistake I think. I have 21 rows missing. May be something wrong with a special character?

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 6584 entries, 0 to 6583
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Primary area    6584 non-null object
Discipline      6584 non-null object
Mydiscipline    6563 non-null object

Comment: @nahusznaj, yes, it is possible. So use `import re` and `pat = r'(\b{}\b)'.format('|'.join([re.escape(item) for item in Mydisciplines]))`

Comment: It is called word boundary, [check this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: thank you! I don't fully understand how your solution works, but it does.

Comment: Hi. I have entries with Discipline "Computation Theory and Mathematics". The filter took them to be "Mathematics" but they need to be "Computer Science". I'll change them manually is not too many, but  maybe you can find a systematic issue with the code?

Comment: @nahusznaj - I check it and do you think this sample data? `d = {
    'Primary area': [
        'Biological Sciences A',
        'Cultures and Cultural Production',
        'Mathematics'
    ],
    'Discipline': [
        'Biochemistry and Molecular Biology',
        'Philosophy',
        'Computation Theory and Mathematics'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


Mydisciplines = ['Biological Sciences A', 'Mathematics', 'Philosophy','Computation Theory']` ?

Comment: @nahusznaj - in `Mydisciplines` are also `Mathematics` and `Computation Theory` ? then possible solition is extract both by `df['Mydisciplines'] = s.str.findall(pat).str.join(', ')`, but not sure if need it.

Comment: This sample data should be good for checking: d = { 'Primary area': [ 'Study of the Human Past', 'Computer Science', 'Mathematics' ], 'Discipline': [ 'History', 'Computation Theory and Mathematics', 'Applied Mathematics' ] } df = pd.DataFrame(data=d). Outcome should be Mydisciplines = ['History', 'Computer Science', 'Mathematics']

Comment: @nahusznaj - i just check it and there is `'problem'` in data - match multiple values. My solution return one value from `Mydisciplines` only. But if need all matching values use `df['Mydisciplines'] = s.str.findall(pat).apply(set).str.join(', ')`

Comment: thanks for taking the time to see this but that's not doing what I needed. For example, an entry with `'Primary area'='Computer Science', 'Discipline' = 'Computation Theory and Mathematics'` is assigned to `'Mydisciplines'='Mathematics, Computer Science'`. But `'Mathematics, Computer Science'` shouldn't be in the list of possible `'Mydisciplines'`, it should have been `'Primary area'='Computer Science', 'Discipline' = 'Computation Theory and Mathematics', 'Mydisciplines'='Computer Science'`.

Comment: @nahusznaj - Hmmm, there is problem with multiple keywords. And `extract` function has to decide, if use first or second or n keyword (not sure if give always first value, last or first sorted, or last sorted...).

Comment: @nahusznaj - possible solution are prioritize one column like `df['Mydisciplines'] = df['Discipline'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).combine_first(df['Primary area'].str.extract(pat, expand=False))` or 

`df['Mydisciplines'] = df['Primary area'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).combine_first(df['Discipline'].str.extract(pat, expand=False))`

Comment: I've decided that my solution is more simple and I will use that instead. I still have an issue with the regex when there's () in the discipline.

Comment: although in fairness, my "solution" does not address the initial question since my solution does not create a new column and yours does! However, I get is what I need easier following the solution I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

What I managed to do was this.

Create a list including all the Disciplines associated with a Primary area:

```
Biological_A = df[(df["Primary area"] == 'Biological Sciences A')].Discipline.unique()
Mathematics = df[(df["Primary area"] == 'Mathematics')].Discipline.unique()
```

Then replace the values in the column Discipline that are in that list:

`for x in Biology_A:
    df.replace({'Discipline': {x:'Biological Sciences A'}}, regex=True, inplace=True)
for x in Mathematics:
    df.replace({'Discipline': {x:'Mathematics'}}, regex=True, inplace=True)`

Repeat this with the other Primary areas as desired.

This code takes

```
    Discipline                              Primary area
0   Biochemistry and Molecular Biology      Biological Sciences A
1   Philosophy                              Cultures and Cultural Production
2   Pure Mathematics                        Mathematics
```

into

```
    Discipline                              Primary area
0   Biological Sciences A                   Biological Sciences A
1   Philosophy                              Cultures and Cultural Production
2   Pure Mathematics                        Mathematics
```

It doesn't really answer the question in that it doesn't create a new column, but this is exactly what I needed despite the wording of the question.